# Glassfish won't start version 3 and 4

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, glassfish

I still having the same problem with glassfish !! I've changed the port and executed the command as admin but it doesn't work..

I also tried the command : **asadmin start-domain --verbose domain1**

I tried also to create my own domain but it still not working...
**Please Help me if you have any idea.**

this is the output (I am using windows 10):

```
C:\glassfish4\bin>asadmin start-domain domain1
Waiting for domain1 to start ..Error starting domain domain1.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 1.
Before it died, it produced the following output:

Syntaxe : java [-options] class [args...]
           (pour l'exécution d'une classe)
   ou  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (pour l'exécution d'un fichier JAR)
où les options comprennent :
    -d32          utilisez le modèle de données 32 bits s'il est disponible
    -d64          utilisez le modèle de données 64 bits s'il est disponible
    -server       pour sélectionner la machine virtuelle "server"
                  La machine virtuelle par défaut est server.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  Liste de répertoires, d'archives JAR et
                   d'archives ZIP séparés par des ;, dans laquelle rechercher les fichiers de classe.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  définition d'une propriété système
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  activation de la sortie en mode verbose
    -version      impression de la version du produit et fin de l'opération
    -version:<value>
                  Avertissement : cette fonctionnalité est en phase d'abandon et sera enlevée
                  dans une version future.
                  exécution de la version spécifiée obligatoire
    -showversion  impression de la version du produit et poursuite de l'opération
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  Avertissement : cette fonctionnalité est en phase d'abandon et sera enlevée
                  dans une version future.
                  inclusion/exclusion des environnements JRE privés de l'utilisateur dans la recherche de version
    -? -help      impression du message d'aide
    -X            impression de l'aide sur les options non standard
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  activation des assertions avec la granularité spécifiée
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  désactivation des assertions avec la granularité spécifiée
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  activation des assertions système
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  désactivation des assertions système
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  chargement de la bibliothèque d'agent natif <libname>, par exemple -agentlib:hprof
                  voir également, -agentlib:jdwp=help et -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  chargement de la bibliothèque d'agent natif via le chemin d'accès complet
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  chargement de l'agent du langage de programmation Java, voir java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  affichage de l'écran d'accueil avec l'image spécifiée
Voir http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html pour plus de détails.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0

Command start-domain failed.
```

Comment: Your Java options aren't correct. Can't tell what they're set to based on this output. My guess; settings that were removed from Java some time ago (based on "ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0"). Try an older version of Java, or a newer version of glassfish.

Comment: Glassfish that am using is the newer version. This morning is working fine for me but after rebooting my computer glassfish won't start!! How can I change the version of java ? in the file assenv.bat ?  ( the path : C:\glassfish4\glassfish\config)

Comment: Setting `JAVA_HOME` in `asenv.bat` will change the Java version, but GlassFish 4 should be fine with Java 7 or 8. GF4 won't work on Java 9, but this is an odd error to see. Is there anything in the server.log?

Comment: I am using java 8. No I had only that output ! There is no error. it just showed me failed start domain

Comment: Can you run other Java applications OK? I assume, by the intellij idea tag, that you can? You could perhaps try extracting GlassFish from the zip file once more so it is completely clean and try that.

Comment: I didn't test other java application. I tried also as u said to extract GlassFish from the zip file once more  but nothing new it doesn't work !! I am lost and don't know what should I do !!! I tried version 3 and 4, both  don't work. It's weird because I haven't that problem last week...